# How to do multiprocessing or multithreading when __name__ will never be equl to '__main__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am currently working on a python script that will modify gcode (code for 3d printing). I have create a python script which use multiporcessing

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  # MultiProcessing
        with Pool() as p:
            resultat = p.map(traitement_gcode_lineaire,liste_traitement)
    if len(resultat)!=0 :
        for result in resultat :
            fichier += result
```

like this, it work perfectly when launch by myself. But for my work I need to implement it on Cura (a slicer of 3d object) but the problem is now `__name__` is never equal to `'__main__'` but to
`'PostProcessingPlugin.PostProcessingPlugin.ModificationGcodeMultiProcessing'` where `'ModificationGcodeMultiProcessing'` is the name of my file.
So i was wandering if any of you know a way to launch multiprocessing/multithreading with the if `__name__ == __main__` or a way to have `__name__` equal to `__name__`.

PS : `traitement_gcode_lineaire` is name of the function I call to modify gcode and `liste_traitement` is a mist with all the arguments the function need.

_I try with :

```
if __name__ == 'PostProcessingPlugin.PostProcessingPlugin.ModificationGcodeMultiProcessing':  # MultiProcessing
```

But it create an infinte loop so a fail
I also try multhreading but it also use `__name__` equal to `__main__`

Comment: Can I ask what context it's not being launched with `__name__ == '__main__'`? That should only happen when it's being imported by some other main script, and doing significant work like that as a side-effect of being imported is not playing nice as a module. Usually you'd have the importer manually trigger such additional work by calling a function or constructing a class that would create and use the pool, and would be implicitly protected by the import guard used by the main script (whatever it happens to be).

Comment: @ShadowRanger it was mentioned that this is to be a plugin to [Cura](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/tree/main). The documentation to writing plugins is a bit lacking... I've been browsing the code, and it seems there may be more integrated ways to create a class which gets registered with the software in various ways which may integrate into various tools within the GUI. To this end, I would say you are correct that the code should only define functions and classes that then Cura calls itself (and is responsible for import guard)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this will behave in a wide variety of environments, but here's some ways to approach this:

- If you are using threads rather than processes, you don't need the import guard at all, but python cannot run many threads in parallel due to the [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). Threads only speed up code which is either waiting on IO (file read/write, network typically) or which is written in another language which specifically releases the thread lock while in compiled code (many `numpy` and `scipy` operations)

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

with ThreadPool() as pool:
    pool.map(...)
```

- If you are using linux, the default context will be "fork", and the import guard is not strictly needed. If you are on MacOS, you can set the context to "fork" manually (although some parts of the OS are not fork-safe)

```py
from multiprocessing import get_context

ctx = get_context("fork")
with ctx.Pool() as pool: #not inside import guard!
    pool.map(...)
```

- Alternatively you can check if `__name__` is **not** the [special name given to child processes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d2340ef25721b6a72d45d4508c672c4be38c67d3/Lib/multiprocessing/spawn.py#L292) in the spawning context. This *should* be reliable, and because spawn has broader compatibility (Windows / certain parts of MacOS) it may be the better solution

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ != "__mp_main__":
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thougths:

Change your code to this:

```
def main(): # Or some equally obvious name like 'run'
        with Pool() as p:
            resultat = p.map(traitement_gcode_lineaire,liste_traitement)
    if len(resultat)!=0 :
        for result in resultat :
            fichier += result

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

If you must do anything in `if __name__ == '__main__':`  try to make it things that can only do when this program is called directly by the user from the command line.

If you intend to call your program from another program than you can easily `import YourModuleName; YourModuleName.main()` and the value of `__name__` doesn't matter and, more importantly, your code [is explicit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python#Principles) in what it's trying to do.

Another thing that is worth mentioning, is that your python file is executed at import.  Though, the the python interpreter does not "step into" any of the function or class definitions; the only reason that the `if __name__=='__main__':` statement works is because the code is run when the import happens and the `if` statement is tested against a magic global and the code inside it is executed.  In otherwords, there's no compiler step to make a `main` function executable, python executes the script file directly.  So, if you *don't* have explicit control to call main manually... take it out of the `if` statement and actually 'just' run it as a script.  I don't really recommend this as a general practice, but I've gotten too old to not be pragmatic about getting a job done.